# Array of Dictionaries contains same dictionary reference for all array elements

Tags: vba

I have an array and within a while loop I insert a row of data into a dictionary, then add each dictionary to the array.

My setup is like this:

```
while something

    Dim MyDict as new Scripting.Dictionary
    MyDict.RemoveAll


    'Add data
    MyDict.add "something","something"


    If Count = 0 Then
        ReDim MyArray(0)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(UBound(MyArray, 1) + 1)
    End If

    'Add the dictionary to the array of dictionaries
    Set MyArray(UBound(MyArray, 1)) = MyDict

wend
```

However, at the end of the while loop the whole array of dictionaries points to the same dictionary- the last one. I thought by declaring the dictionary within the while loop and using New, along with removeall I would avoid this....

How do I ensure each dictionary is not just a reference to the final one inserted?

Comment: I don't understand clearly what you're trying to achieve.
Have you tried Declaring MyDic outsite the while loop and then doing "Set MyDic=new Scripting.Dictionary" within the loop, instead?

Comment: Kovags is correct, without the `Set` you have an array with n elements holding references to the same dictionary instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Kovags is telling you:

```
Dim MyDict as Scripting.Dictionary

while something      

    Set MyDict = new Scripting.Dictionary     

    'Add data     
    MyDict.add "something","something"       

     If Count = 0 Then
         ReDim MyArray(0)
     Else
         ReDim Preserve MyArray(UBound(MyArray, 1) + 1)
     End If      

    'Add the dictionary to the array of dictionaries     
    Set MyArray(UBound(MyArray, 1)) = MyDict  

wend
```

...though I think you may find it easier to use a collection for this insted of an array.