# VBA Dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am creating unique collections from every column in my sheet under the column headings using dictionary object. Column headings are in Row 1.

Problem is my dictionaries contains unique items from previous columns. for example if call a dictionary of column 4, it contains all unique items and headings from columns 1,2,3. I need only unique items from that perticular column. Any idea how to correct this code?.

```
Sub cre_Dict()
Dim fulArr As Variant

Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

With Sheets("Database")
        fulArr = .Range("A1:IO27") 'assign whole table to array
        For j = 1 To UBound(fulArr, 2) 'looping from 1st column to last column
            For i = 2 To UBound(fulArr, 1) 'looping from row2 to last row
                If Len(fulArr(i, j)) > 0 Then 'if not blank cell
                    d00 = d.Item(fulArr(i, j)) 'add to dictionary
                End If
            Next i
            d(fulArr(1, j)) = d.keys 'create dictionary under column heading
        Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You should add some comments, both for us as well as yourself; it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Almost same code as some previous questions, no clear explanations and you still work with an empty dictionary...

Comment: How is my dictionary empty?. d is global object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of Dictionaries contains same dictionary reference for all array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367831/array-of-dictionaries-contains-same-dictionary-reference-for-all-array-elements)

Comment: @Shan `How is my dictionary empty?. d is global object.` - How are **we** supposed to know that unless you put it in your question?

Comment: OK My mistake............

Comment: OK thanks..i will try and come back .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below example, based on your code with minor changes I have made:

```
Dim d As Object

Sub cre_Dict()
    Dim fulArr As Variant
    Dim q As Object
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    fulArr = Sheets("Database").Range("A1:IO27") 'assign whole table to array
    For j = 1 To UBound(fulArr, 2) 'looping from 1st column to last column
        Set q = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 2 To UBound(fulArr, 1) 'looping from row2 to last row
            If Len(fulArr(i, j)) > 0 Then 'if not blank cell
                q(fulArr(i, j)) = Empty 'add to dictionary
            End If
        Next i
        d(fulArr(1, j)) = q.Keys 'create dictionary under column heading
    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got this correct, you have duplicates in different columns. So basically your keys in the dictionary are not unique as you iterate over columns. If that's the case, when you add your keys  to the dictionary, create a composite key. For example something like:

Dim sKey as string
sKey = "A~" & "ABCD"

This will then make the key unique for column A.
When processing the collection, you can strip out the "A~" part for each column.