# is it possbile to create an collection of arrays in vba?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, collections

first of all, i'd like to say, i've sarched thorugh the net, but i haven't run into such a thing. i've seen collection of collections, or array of arrays, but not a collection of array.

what i want to do is, to collect ID's in collections for each District. Finally, i will join the values in the collections with Join function and ";" as delimiter, and then print them in a range of 4 column as a lookup list, for each class. For example;

Class2(0) will include 54020 and 30734, class2(1) will include 58618, class1(4) will include none, class3(7) will include 35516,34781 and 56874, and so on.

i want to loop through column C and put a select case statment to check the class and then assign the values to collections

```
Sub dict_coll()
Dim class1() As New Collection
Dim class2() As New Collection
Dim class3() As New Collection
Dim class4() As New Collection

Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

Set dRange = range(range("a2"), range("a2").End(xlDown))

i = 0
For Each d In dRange
    If Not dict.Exists(d.Value) Then
        dict.Add key:=d.Value, item:=i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next d

Set cRange = range(range("c2"), range("c2").End(xlDown))
For Each c In cRange
    Select Case c.Value
        Case "class1"
            class1(dict(c.offset(0,-2).value)).Add c.Offset(0, 1).Value 'fails here
        Case "class2"
            class2(dict(c.offset(0,-2).value)).Add c.Offset(0, 1).Value 'fails here
        Case "class3"
            class3(dict(c.offset(0,-2).value)).Add c.Offset(0, 1).Value 'fails here
        Case Else
            class4(dict(c.offset(0,-2).value)).Add c.Offset(0, 1).Value 'fails here
    End Select
Next c
End Sub
```

[image]

and what i want to see is as foloowing:
[image]
is there any easier and proper way of what i wanna do? any help wil be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: in the 3rd paragraph, i mistakenly wrote class1(7010) and so on, but it is actually suppoesed to be class1(0), because of the dictionary. sorry for that.

Comment: Is [VBA Dictionary of dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807598/vba-dictionary-of-dictionaries) what you are looking for?

Comment: i'm not sure, maybe it is, but i dont know how to do

Comment: It isn't quite clear what is a data structure you want get. Please edit your question to elaborate what structure do you want and to correct the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: hi omega, i inserted the output that i want

Comment: File link is here: http://www.megafileupload.com/6z95/dict.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

I didnt see that sb variable defined in your code.

Anyway, for me I see a case of straightforward arrays: There is  fixed dimension of classes so it good enough for me. Furthermore, you can print back to worksheet so easily.

```
Public Sub test()

  Const strPrefix = "class"

  Dim districtRange As Range, outputRange As Range, r As Range
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, x As Long, y As Long
  Dim district As String, str As String, idVal As String

  Dim arr2 As Variant

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ReDim arr(1 To 5, 1 To 1)
  arr(1, 1) = "District"
  arr(2, 1) = "Class 1"
  arr(3, 1) = "Class 2"
  arr(4, 1) = "Class 3"
  arr(5, 1) = "Class 4"

  Set districtRange = Range(Range("A2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
  arr2 = districtRange.Value
  For x = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
        district = arr2(x, 1)
        i = Val(Mid(arr2(x, 3), Len(strPrefix) + 1))
        idVal = arr2(x, 2)
        j = inArray(arr, district, 1)       'returns -1 if not found
        If j >= 0 Then
              arr(i + 1, j) = IIf(arr(i + 1, j) = "", idVal, arr(i + 1, j) & ";" & idVal)
        Else
              ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 5, 1 To UBound(arr, 2) + 1)
              arr(1, UBound(arr, 2)) = district
              arr(i + 1, UBound(arr, 2)) = idVal
        End If
  Next x

  Set outputRange = Range("E1")
  outputRange.Resize(UBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
  outputRange.Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlAscending

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function inArray(arr As Variant, k As String, Optional rowNum As Long, Optional colNum As Long) As Long

  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  inArray = -1

  If rowNum Then
        For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
              If arr(rowNum, i) = k Then
                    inArray = i
                    Exit Function
              End If
        Next i
  Else
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
              If arr(i, colNum) = k Then
                    inArray = i
                    Exit Function
              End If
        Next i
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: oh thanks dude, it worked, your solution is so clever, how on earth couldnt think of it. by the way, "sb" in my code was supposed to be "c", i've changed the code a bit so others can understand it, but i forgot to change "sb". anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: Hey, thanks man. Glad to help :-) Can you tick my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

by the way, i've found another solution, usinf both dictionary and 3-dimension array.

```
Sub test()
Dim Blg As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim Sgm As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim Siciller() As String

ReDim Siciller(0 To 23, 0 To 3, 0 To 5)

Set alanBolge = range(range("a2"), range("a2").End(xlDown))
Set alanSegment = range(range("c2"), range("c2").End(xlDown))

i = 0
For Each d In alanBolge
    If Not Blg.Exists(d.Value) Then
        Blg.Add Key:=d.Value, item:=i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next d

k = 0
For Each d In alanSegment
    If Not Sgm.Exists(d.Value) Then
        Sgm.Add Key:=d.Value, item:=k
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next d



'data reading
For Each d In alanBolge
    Siciller(Blg(d.Value), Sgm(d.Offset(0, 2).Value), dolusay(Siciller, Blg(d.Value), Sgm(d.Offset(0, 2).Value)) + 1) = d.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next d


'output
For x = 1 To 4
    For y = 1 To 24
        Set h = Cells(1 + y, 5 + x)
        h.Select
        h.Value = sonucgetir(Siciller, Blg(h.Offset(0, -x).Value), Sgm(h.Offset(-y, 0).Value))
    Next y
Next x


End Sub
Public Function dolusay(ByVal data As Variant, ByVal i1 As Integer, ByVal i2 As Integer) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    For j = 0 To UBound(data, 3) - 1
        If Len(data(i1, i2, j)) > 0 Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    dolusay = count
End Function
Public Function sonucgetir(ByVal data As Variant, ByVal i1 As Integer, ByVal i2 As Integer) As String
    sonucgetir = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(data, 3)
        If Len(data(i1, i2, i)) > 0 Then
            x = data(i1, i2, i) & ";" & x
            sonucgetir = Left(x, Len(x) - 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Hi ExcelinEfendisi, the thing about Dictionary is that it has a nice set of built-in methods to check the various items.