# VBA: Split multiline string into list with dictionaries

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

Hoi everybody,

I have the following problem: I have a multiline string and want to split it into a list with dictionaries.

As an example, I have the following string:

```
input = "Bla Bla2 Bla3" & vbLf & "Bla21 Bla22 Bla23"
```

And I want to split it into an array, where each entry contains 1 line (i.e., first entry first line and so on). The entries themselfes should be dictionaries, where each column (words separated by " ") is defined by a word.

As an example, here we have "col1", "col2" and "col3".

The result should be a list with 2 elements - and each element should be a dictionary, where d("col1") contains "Bla" for the first entry and "Bla21" for the second entry.

I was able to split the string and feed e.g., the first column into a final array, by splitting the input

```
    ar = Split(input,vbLf,,vbTextCompare)
    pos = 0
```

And then interating over that array - dynamically adding entries to a result array.

```
    Do while pos < UBound(ar)
       line = Split(ar(pos))
       if Len(Join(result)) = 0 Then
           ReDim Preserve result(0)
       else
           ReDim Preserve result(Ubound(result)+1)
       result(Ubound(result)) = line(0)
       pos = pos + 1
   Loop
```

Now - my problem is generalizing this for all column - i.e., integrating the dictionary into this.

I added initializing a new dictionary below "line = Split...)" like this

```
 Set d = New dictionary
```

And set the values directly below the if clause

```
 d("col1") = line(0)
 d("col2") = line(1)
 d("col3") = line(2)
```

And finally, I want to set the array element equal to this dictionary:

```
result(Ubound(result)) = d
```

However, this does not work. When running it like this, I get an "Argument not optional" error. When adding a set, i.e.:

```
Set result(Ubound(result)) = d
```

I get a "Object required" error.

Can someone help me to fix this error?

Thank you and kind regards.

/edit: To make life easier, here the actual function I am currently using:

```
Function IterateString(text as String)
      Dim pos as Integer
      Dim entry() as String
      Dim line() as String
      Dim result() as String
      Dim MyDict as Scripting.Dictionary

      entry = Split(text,vbLf,,vbTextCompare)
      pos = 0
      result = Array()

      Do While pos < Ubound(entry)
        If Trim$(entry(pos)) <> "" Then
           line = Split(entry(pos))
           Set MyDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
           If Len(Join(result)) = 0 Then
              ReDim result(0,0)
           Else
              ReDim Preserve result(UBound(result,1) + 1)
           End If
           MyDict.Add "col1",line(0)
           MyDict.Add "col2",line(1)
           Set result(Ubound(result,1)) = MyDict
        End If
        pos = pos + 1
     Loop
     IterateString = result
End Function
```

Comment: Where is `result` defined ? Is your dictionary limited to only each line? Then the lines itself are the array elements. So something like `ar(N)("Col 3")` is acceptable ?

Comment: result is defined at the very top (just like pos, line and ar) - pos As Integer, and line() As String,result() As String
Yes the dictionary should be limited to each line - so each line contains its own dictionary - and ar(N)("Col 3") should be acceptable

Currently, only setting the dictionary to be equal to a list entry does not work - the rest seems to work

Comment: OK, But result was never assigned a value ..

Comment: so my solution looks essentially like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367831/array-of-dictionaries-contains-same-dictionary-reference-for-all-array-elements - the last line just does not work

Comment: Not by any PC right now, so a blind shot: try “Dim result() As Dictionary” along with  “Set result(Ubound(result)) = d”

Comment: Added the code of the current function. Even adding initializing the array (result = Array()) did not solve the error.
Can someone help me here?

Comment: Did you try my piece of advice? (i.e. “Dim result() As Scripting.Dictionary”)

Comment: Thank you - I did not really understand why I need this - but I do now and it works - thanks :)